# i want add multiple product using php session

Tags: php, arrays, session

I want to print both

```
<?php

//in file A
$_SESSION['cart']['prices'] = array('1000');
$_SESSION['cart']['services'] = array('game');

//In File B
$_SESSION['cart']['prices'] = array('2000');
$_SESSION['cart']['services'] = array('game2');

//in file C
foreach ($_SESSION['cart']['services'] as $key => $service) {
    echo $service . ' = ' . $_SESSION['cart']['prices'][$key] . '<br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: and what did you get ?

Comment: edit your question. . make it clear. .

Comment: You can't have same keys twice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use this :

```
$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][] = array('1000');
$_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = array('game');

//In File B
$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][] = array('2000');
$_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = array('game2');
```

According to the current data foreach loop will execute two times. It will print Array as `$service` is `array array('1000')` and `array('2000')` same as for `$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][$key]`

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart']['services'] as $key => $service) {
    echo $service . ' = ' . $_SESSION['cart']['prices'][$key] . '<br />';
}
```

Try this :

```
$array1 = array('1000','2000');
$array2 = array('game1','game2');

foreach($array1 as $index=>$key)
{
    $_SESSION['cart']['prices'][] = $key;
    $_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = $array2[$index];
}



foreach ($_SESSION['cart']['services'] as $key => $service) {
    echo $service . ' = ' . $_SESSION['cart']['prices'][$key] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Error=>E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Array to string conversion -- at line 11

Comment: E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Array to string conversion -- at line 11
Array = Array

Comment: echo $service . ' = ' . $_SESSION['cart']['prices'][$key] . '<br />';    //in this line

Comment: Read my answer again...According to the current data foreach loop will execute two times. It will print Array as $service is array('1000') and array('2000') same as for $_SESSION['cart']['prices'][$key]

Comment: please give any solution. actually i want to add multiple services and price  to 'add to cart' page

Comment: From where you are getting such values please share array('1000');
array('2000');

Comment: sorry unable to understand please explain in briefly

Comment: i have to store array from different pages. cant add like this $array2 = array('game1','game2');